# CSS-Background focused no matter resolution of browser

Tags: html, css, image, background

Right now when you go to this link:http://rawgallery.us/user/login
the background is cut off. It should look like this picture no matter the resolution of the browser window: http://rawgallery.us/CarlisleBackDropWallRoom.png

I am still learning CSS, so I used this code that was suppose to cover the background everywhere, which works :

```
html { 
  background: url("CarlisleBackDropWallRoom.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

my #page is setup like this:

```
#page {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height:960px;
  min-width:960px;
  max-height:1200px;
  max-width:1200px;

}
```

Does the html tag override the page tag?

Can someone tell me how I can view the whole background image if the browser window is 500x700 or 1200x1500 for example?

Thanks!

Comment: Please avoid linking to external sites. Try recreating your problem with a Fiddle instead.

Comment: As a sidenote, I would almost certainly leave a website with a full page background that would actually still be loading right now.

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer `background-size:contain`, which fits the background image into its container rather than attempting to cover both width and height of the container.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values):

> ["contain"] specifies that the background image should be scaled to be
>   as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than
>   or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning
>   area.

Here's the CSS:

```
html { 
  background: url("/sites/default/files/imgs/CarlisleBackDropWallRoom.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4SZ7/).

Please note the [browser compatibility of `background-size`](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts).

Comment: Given the type of image this is, with the hard color at the bottom (the wood), you may do well to position the image at the bottom. `background-position: 0 100%;`

If using CSS3 is not an option, then CSS tricks has a few alternatives here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/